# Google Chrome suddenly increased size (see picture)

Tags: nvidia, google-chrome

I now find Google Chrome in this state (Probably after a system upgrade) :

[image]

On the left the unity icons are at default size, it is chrome maybe 4-8 times bigger!

```
$ google-chrome --version
Google Chrome 43.0.2357.125

$ uname -a
Linux gru 3.19.0-21-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Sun Jun 14 18:31:11 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

xrandr -d :0 -q
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1280 x 720, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected primary 1280x720+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 708mm x 398mm
   1280x720       60.0*+   59.9     50.0
   1920x1080      59.9     50.0     30.0     25.0     24.0     60.1     60.0     50.0
   1024x768       60.0
   800x600        60.3
   720x576        50.0     50.1
   720x480        60.0     59.9     60.1
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Roll your mousewheel.

Comment: That works with the page itself, unfortunately not with everything else.

Comment: Duplicate on SuperUser: [Chrome GUI is too big as of 43.0.2357.124-1](http://superuser.com/q/925762).

Comment: When I first read the subject line, before reading the rest of your question, I thought you meant the size of the program - and that might have been caused by the code they have just about admitted they have added to chrome which can automatically turn on your microphone and record (for them) everything they hear, maybe even when chrome isn't even running! (That last part might be a Windows/Android thing.) Just wanted to say ... I see you got the answer to your actual question below.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

1. First , close all instances of Google Chrome.

   ```
   killall chrome
   ```
2. Open a terminal and run this command

   ```
   google-chrome --high-dpi-support=1 --force-device-scale-factor=1
   ```

   Now open again, it would solve the issue.

Comment: After a `killall chrome` that worked! Thanks